# Time series decomposition and graphing from custom metrics in Azure Logs

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, kql

While learning Azure Log processing I started recording simple queue counts as metrics via AppInsight. Currently I process them in a fairly simple way and show them in a same graph.

The simple query is like

```
customMetrics
| where cloud_RoleName == "abc" and name endswith "_ApproximateMessagesCount"
| summarize avg(valueSum) by name, bin(timestamp, 30s)
| render timechart;
```

Then I thought that I could try forecastig on these counts and draw the forecast together with the counts. So I went to read the documentation and found an example on time series decomposition as described at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/anomaly-detection#time-series-decomposition-model. Perfect!

So I modified the query a bit to

```
let min_t = startofday(now());
let max_t = endofday(now());
let dt = 1h;
let horizon=24h;
customMetrics
| where cloud_RoleName == "abc" and name endswith "_ApproximateMessagesCount"
| make-series queueCount=avg(valueSum) on timestamp from min_t to max_t step dt by name
| extend forecast = series_decompose_forecast(queueCount, toint(horizon/dt))
| render timechart with(title="abc", ysplit=panels)
```

Alas! A few problems I don't understand really:

1. How to show a graph of actual counts together with a forecast of counts.
2. How could one split a graph on each "swim line" with each swim line having the the actual counts over time as well as the forecast? In the example the `ysplit=panels` seem to achieve this, but maybe it doesn't work like that with multiple graphs?

I may have also misunderstood on how `make-series` and `extend` function. I mean that I see a graph from which I can determine the counts and then the graphs go to zero quickly, maybe because the forecast is so. So, effectively the actual `queueCount` is shown on `y axis` (while all the graphs are on the same swimlane).

The test code to report queue counts is just simple

```
string queueName = $"{queueName}_ApproximateMessagesCount";
int queueLength = <someValue>;
TelemetryClient.TrackMetric(new MetricTelemetry
{
    Name = queueName,
    Sum = queueLength,
    Count = 1,
    Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you have both the actual counts and the forecast in the table then 'render timechart shows both. Note that you need to specify *to max_t+horizon* in make-series.

```
let min_t = datetime(2017-01-05);
let max_t = datetime(2017-02-03 22:00);
let dt = 2h;
let horizon=7d;
demo_make_series2
| make-series num=avg(num) on TimeStamp from min_t to max_t+horizon step dt by sid 
| where sid == 'TS1'   //  select a single time series just to get cleaner visualization
| extend forecast = series_decompose_forecast(num, toint(horizon/dt))
| render timechart
```

[image: Traffic counts with forecast]

2. *ysplit=panels* works only in KE (Kusto Explorer, the desktop app)
3. Don't undrstand your last question re. make-series and extend. Please clarify.

Comment: I'll accept this so it's not lingering here. The last one was about creating several graphs instead of just one. Otherwise the query looks quite the same as mine and that what MS docs tell. :)